# Ant socket task not working on mac

Tags: macos, sockets, tomcat, ant

I got the following on a build.xml

```
<target name="check-port" description="Check whether Tomcat is running">
    <condition property="tomcat.running">
        <socket server="localhost" port="8080"/> 
    </condition>
</target>
```

It suddenly stopped working for mac, on windows it works fine, but on mac it shows as true even when I got nothing running on localhost:8080.

I'm not sure why this is happening or why it is working on windows. It used to work on mac...

I'm testing on OSX Yosemite version 10.10.2

What could this be related to? How can I fix it?

Comment: Forgive the presumption, but _how_ do you know there's nothing listening on that port?

Comment: `sudo lsof -i -P | grep 8080`
Also when I start tomcat manually it doesn't complain

Comment: afsg77, that's very interesting. I've answered as best I can given the info, but I think this may well require some deep investigation. Still, hopefully the answer will give you a clearer indication of where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

It seems that ESET antivirus is starting a process call 'esets_proxy' on localhost:8080, but here is the funny thing it is not visible through `lsof` or `netstat`. Strangely when I started a wildfly on 8080 it become visible. But only while the wildfly is running, after I shut it down it stops showing. I removed ESET and the ant socket task stop showing port 8080 as in use.

Thanks @paxdiablo your help was really useful!

Answer (score 1):

The *first* thing I would do is to emulate the behaviour of the `ant` condition code by compiling and running the following code:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("down");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("up");
    }
}
```

---

If *that* outputs `up` when Tomcat is not running then you have a fundamental disagreement between `java` and `lsof` in terms of what constitutes "upness", and one that needs to be investigated.

One way to see if there actually *is* something there is to try to connect to it, such as with:

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

If that connects, I'd generally try `lsof` to see what process has got it but, as you state, that appears not to work. It may be that a different tool like:

```
netstat -na | grep ':8080 '
```

would do the trick.

---

If it outputs `down` then you have a different issue, either some problem within `ant` or possibly your build process itself starting up the server (or a different server). That will *also* require further investigation but you'll at least have narrowed the problem down.

One thing you might try then is to run that Java code within your build process itself, to see what it thinks at the same time `ant` is telling you the server is there.

Comment: it is showing `up`...   but I can start the tomcat without any complain on the port 8080

Comment: @afsg77, see the update on trying `telnet` - not sure _what_ machinations OSX may pull but there may actually be a server there event though you've turned off Tomcat.

Comment: It is connecting but it is been closed...
`tester$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: How can I see what is using that port?

Comment: Well, `lsof` would seem to be the tool for the job :-) But, since that's what you're concerned about, I've added a `netstat` variant. You might also want to try `lsof -i :8080 -P`.

Comment: found this http://superuser.com/questions/701779/whats-up-with-port-8080-on-my-osx-box but I don't have the AnyConnect installed...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Kaspersky anti-virus on OS X, which is starting an invisible process (no netstat) on localhost  8080.